# Cayley transform is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ and write $\mathscr{L}_h$ for the set of self-adjoint operators on $H$. The Cayley-transform is defined to be the map
$$\mathscr{L}_h \to U(H): x \mapsto (x-i)(x+i)^{-1}$$

I want to show that this map is well-defined, i.e. that $x+i$ is invertible in $B(H)$ and that $(x-i)(x+i)^{-1}$ is a unitary.

I proceeded as follows:

The $C^*$-algebra $C^*(x,1)$ generated by $x$ and $1$ is abelian and unital, so it is $*$-isomorphic to $C(X)$ for some compact Hausdorff space $X$. Then the statement becomes trivial because the function $x + i$ does not take the value $0$ (because $x$ is real-valued) and the calculation
$$\overline{\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)} \frac{x-i}{x+i}= \frac{x^2+1}{x^2+1}=1$$
shows that $(x-i)(x+i)^{-1}$ is unitary in $C(X)$ and thus also in $C^*(x,1)$ and thus also in $B(H)$, as desired.

Would this be a correct way to show this? It is just a quick sanity check.

Comment: That's correct, although I wouldn't use the same symbol to denote the element of $B(H)$ and the function on $C(\sigma(x))$. Moreover, you need to use that $X$ can be taken as a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ for the function $x$ to even make sense.

Comment: @MaoWao Why do we need that $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$? I don't see how this gives problems if it is not.

Comment: The function $x$ (I guess you mean $x\mapsto x$) is only a real-valued function if it is defined on a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah okay I see what you are saying. By definition of the functional calculus we can always take $X = \sigma(x)$ so since $x$ is self-adjoint there is no problem. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is fine. But you don't really need functional calculus here.

Since $x$ is selfadjoint, $\sigma(x)\subset\mathbb R$. Then $\sigma(x+i)\subset\mathbb R+i$. In particular, $0\not\in\sigma(x+i)$ and so $x+i$ is invertible. Same argument works for $x-i$.

Because $x+i$ commutes with $x-i$, so does $(x+i)^{-1}$. Then$\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$
\begin{align}
[(x-i)(x+i)^{-1}]^*(x-i)(x+i)^{-1}
&=(x-i)^{-1}(x+i)(x -i)(x+i)^{-1}\abajo
&=(x+i)(x-i)^{-1}(x-i)(x+i)^{-1}\abajo
&=(x+i)(x+i)^{-1}=1. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Here is a follow-up question, if you havr time/interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348665/takesaki-lemma-4-5